# How could i change the size of scrollingActivity title?

Tags: android

**How could i change the size of scrollingActivity title?**
Could I change it in XML file or it might be in jave code, my app designed with Material Design, I need something work on SDK8 or grater any help would greatly apprciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `android:titleEnable="false"` to CollapsingToolbarLayout and then make a textView with custom style .